# What is wrong with this Windows shutdown command?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, shutdown

I am using Windows 7 and XP. I want to run a script to run this command:

```
shutdown /p /f /t 120
```

On Windows 7, it shows that an error occurred, but I think I am using it correctly.

Comment: What error? Is there a specific error you can quote here for us to see?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You are using conflicting switches.

- `/p` – Turn off the local computer with no time-out or warning. Can be used with the `/f` option.
- `/t` –  Set the time-out period before shutdown to `xxx` seconds.

You are telling it to shutdown now with `/p` ***and*** shutdown in 120 seconds with `/t`.

Comment: Learn something new... I always do `/s /f /t 0`... glad to know I can be lazy and just do `/p /f` now. That's five key strokes I'll save!

Answer (score 5):

You should use

```
shutdown /f /t 120
```

Parameters **/p** and **/t** are incompatible.

Check [Windows 7 shutdown command syntax](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732503.aspx) for other parameters and more info.

Comment: you need a toggle for shutdown: R for restart, S for shutdown, H for hibernate, P for shutdown now (can't use T), etc. `/f /t 120`, etc

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you might want to try

```
shutdown -s -f -t 120
```

This will force close all running programs and shut your computer down after 120 seconds.